# Put monitor to sleep when locking screen in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, display-settings

Ubuntu turns off my monitor after a certain duration (perhaps 10 minutes - didn't count exactly) after I lock my screen.

Is there a way to adjust the waiting time before the display goes to sleep? Or an option to put the display to sleep if the screen is locked?

EDIT: The power management options do not seem to work for me. Whatever value I set the display sleep time to, it takes the same amount of time to turn off.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adjust these settings in Power Management.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to see the option for putting the display to sleep after x minutes. Is there a way I can put it to sleep when locking the screen?

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Even after setting the display sleep time to 1 minute, it takes its own time to turn off.

Comment: Did you make sure that the option was committed? Leaving the dialog option & changing the value doesn't commit it. Beyond that, I'm out of ideas.